# How many relationships does neo4j support in a graph?

Tags: neo4j

I read from a 2016 Neo's video that Neo4j supports up to 65000 relationships in a graph. Is that still true? My impression is that it could be billions, node size of course. What about relationship size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [this post](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/) from the official Neo4j Blog one of the top 3 things released with Neo4j 3.0.0 is:

> Completely redesigned internals that **remove all previous limits on the
>   number of nodes, relationships and properties** that can be stored and
>   indexed

That is: there is no limit.

Comment: What about relation types, as @sjc noted below? It's unclear whether it's no limit on relationship counts or relationship types.

Comment: Nowadays I'm pretty sure there are no official limitations at all. I cant see any reason to for neo4j to say: well we can handle like 10 millions relationship types. No one will ever use this much relationship types. If anyone does its probably a failure in the graph design. In this case I would just say there is "no" limit.

Comment: “No one will ever use this much relationship types.” Challenge accepted! :D :D :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that limit was for relationship *types*, not relationships (edges) . I am currently running a graph with 10 million + edges